# ColdFusion - How to read user name instead of login name

Tags: coldfusion

I have inherited a ColdFusion application (and I'm a noob in ColdFusion) which uses GetAuthUser() to read the name of the logged in user, and then appends @mycompany.com to send emails.

We are going to be migrated to a new domain, under which we are receiving user names that do not match our email addresses.

For example, I login as rickhodder and my email address is rickhodder@mycompany.com, and my login under the new domain is C12345, but my email address will still be rickhodder@mycompany.com.

From some research online I see that ColdFusion doesnt go against active directory, it goes against the NT Domain.

Is there a way under ColdFusion to read the email associated with a user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think CF is going to provide you with that information 'out of the box'. You probably want to look at the CFLDAP functionality and use that to look up user information from your AD server, which ought to include the information you need.

If you go this route, you can use your own details to connect for development, but make sure you get an account created to do the LDAP connections with in production. It should have password set not to expire and not have permission to login or do much else. It's likely your domain admin will know what you're after far better than I can explain.